# API gateway proxy integration with lambda function in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

When I set CDK as following , and deploy them. the two content was generated in api gateway.

```
    new LambdaRestApi(this,"api",{
      handler:lambdaFunction
    });
```

I totally beginner this kind of API manipulation and have questions.

① what is `{proxy+}` ?

② what is the difference between following two API ?

③ How can I see payload which will be passed to lambda function ?

If someone has opinion or materials please let me know.

Thanks

[image: api gateway]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the [proxy+](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-settings-method-request.html#api-gateway-proxy-resource) is to enable the following URLs to work with your function:

```
https://44444.execute-api.gggg.amazonaws.com/test-invoke-stage/some/path1/path3
https://44444.execute-api.gggg.amazonaws.com/test-invoke-stage
https://44444.execute-api.gggg.amazonaws.com/test-invoke-stage/test/gggg
https://44444.execute-api.gggg.amazonaws.com/test-invoke-stage/test/5
```

without `proxy+` only the following will work:

```
https://44444.execute-api.gggg.amazonaws.com/test-invoke-stage
```

So the  `proxy+` is able to accept everything past `/test-invoke-stage` as it matches every path starting with `/test-invoke-stage`.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I wonder why the two component were generated. it looks like only `{proxy+}` is needed ! thanks.

Comment: @Heisenberg I'm not sure how CDK does this under the hood.